# Do we have a logical reasoning behind missing geography datatype in SqlDbType enum

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqldbtype

I was just wondering if there is any logical or architectural opinion to not to include geography datatype in SqlDbType enum in c#

They have added SqlDataType in a new assembly named  "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo" which contains geography datatype.
But why this much separation?
When we use SqlCommand object to query sql server we don't have any SqlDataType parameter in its constructor.

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as per this link it doesn't map geography to any type in SqlDbType enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

Geography and other spatial data types are not native SQL data types. They are implemented as CLR User Defined Types (`SqlDbType.Udt`).

You can find more information about working with UDTs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131080.aspx